# How to create textbox on Google Site and send its value to a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, google-sites

There is a google site. I need to add a text box and button, and a service (script) which can send a data of a textbox to a specified spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) and [Insert that into the site](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en).  [This video shows how](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpjqHbeCwI8).  The other option would be [custom code, saved as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and Inserted using an Include Gadget found under Insert->More Gadgets.  For just 1 field, I would go with the Google Form.

Comment: Thank you Karl. But GForm is not a solution for this time. I need to change dynamically 1 cell of GSheet from the site which has already attached GForm. I need something with Web App using doGet etc.. with Gadget, but I couldn't find any working simple example...

Comment: In conjunction with the doGet functions in the above Web App page link, I like reusing the code from this [Mail Merge Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) Especially from the getRowsData function down in the Full Code section. It allows for easy iteration and manipulation of the existing data.  Anything I have done to manipulate existing data uses that code and the [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) often with [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Also, IF you are changing an item submitted from the form, you may want to use a link to the form submission to change it, as opposed to changing the value in the spreadsheet.  The value is stored in the Form as well and you have a disconnect if you edit the spreadsheet item without editing the form response.  There is code in [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/LSKKCR3VHC8) to save the Edit Form Response URL

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script [\Here]](https://scripts.google.com), then make it extract a document, after that you allow the user to edit it through your site and only there then, add that to the search bar by editTaskbar in the embed section then well in the {} do this: s+2%[where you want it to go ex:(search)this adds it to the search bar]=docs.[name of document].name there you can make it add to a textbox that you added.

EX:

almost to limit of characters so go to scripts.google.com and Ctrl+V after googleing "how to extract and add a doc to a site in google sites" oh instead of doc do sheet. Forgot it was sheets Sorry.